# Error NG0203 when trying to import material

Tags: javascript, angular, dependency-injection, frontend

I've been having an issue trying to import material. I've used similar code to the examples they have on material.angular.io yet I get the "inject() must be called from an injection context..." error. I've just been trying to get this to work as a simple table since I'm mostly required to focus on the design part rather than the extensive functionality behind it.

main.ts

```
import { AppComponent } from './app/app.component';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';

bootstrapApplication(AppComponent).catch(err => console.error(err));
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MatTableModule } from '@angular/material/table';

interface brojInfo {
  broj: number,
  ime: string,
  prezime: string
}

var counter: brojInfo[] = [];

for (var i = 0; i <= 1000; i++) {
  counter.push({ broj: i, ime: "Name " + i, prezime: "Surname " + i });
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrl: './app.component.css',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [MatTableModule]
})

export class AppComponent {
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['broj', 'ime', 'prezime'];
  dataSource = counter;
}
```

app.component.html

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">
  <ng-container matColumnDef="broj">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Broj </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.broj}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="ime">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Ime </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.ime}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="prezime">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Prezime </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.prezime}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
```

I'm sorry if this question is too simple, but I've gone through all of the SO questions relating to this issue that Google showed me, the documentation itself, and I can't for the love of it figure this out. This is my first rodeo with not only Angular, but front end itself. Thank you for your time.

I've tried multiple ways that I could find to possibly write the `imports: []` part, even tried to make the app.module.ts file and use it instead of the app.component.ts file import in main.ts, but I still had the same error.

EDIT: Forgot to mention I also tried to add the `paths:` to tsconfig.app.json and that other thing (forgot the word) to angular.json that worked for some other peeps.

EDIT 2: The error specifically appears when I put the `imports: [MatTableModule]` line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer! Since this project was made with a VS2022 template, the Package Manager Console decided to install the damn @angular/material package in the main directory of the project where the solution file is rather than the actual subfolder where the package.json is.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/35586) on the Angular repo.

Basically, you have a dependency issue, there is more than one instance `@angular/core` in your bundle.

`npm ls @angular/core` should be able to give you some insights

Comment: I have done `npm ls @angular/core` and there is only one instance of it, 17.0.8. I have tried removing the node_modules folder and doing `npm install` but that did not get rid of the issue either.

Answer (score 0):

The code provided works fine, Please find below a working stackblitz, kindly modify the stackblitz and share back if the issue persists!

Search your source code for some place you are using `inject()` maybe that will bring you closer to a solution!

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { MatTableModule } from '@angular/material/table';
import 'zone.js';

interface brojInfo {
  broj: number;
  ime: string;
  prezime: string;
}

var counter: brojInfo[] = [];

for (var i = 0; i <= 1000; i++) {
  counter.push({ broj: i, ime: 'Name ' + i, prezime: 'Surname ' + i });
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  template: `
    <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">
  <ng-container matColumnDef="broj">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Broj </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.broj}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="ime">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Ime </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.ime}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="prezime">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Prezime </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.prezime}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
  `,
  imports: [MatTableModule],
})
export class App {
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['broj', 'ime', 'prezime'];
  dataSource = counter;
}

bootstrapApplication(App);
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-zqqpyn)

Comment: Sadly since this project has been made from scratch in VS2022 for the sole purpose of working on designs for material tables there are no places at all that use inject() anywhere in the <10 files that exist inside the solution.